# Dx warning issues with latest Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I update the ADT, and reinstall android SDK. After that I try to run a program, but it does not work. console output is like below:

> Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class
>       org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase$1 that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably
>   produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file
>   format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from
>   source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is
>   that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate
>   that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class
>       org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1
>   that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This
>   class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile
>   the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without
>   specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will
>   incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

and a dialog pops up from eclipse, saying that your project contains errors, please fix them before running.

The org.apache.commons.httpclient appearing in the output is in commons-httpclient-3.1.jar. I can not use the latest httpclient package from apache to replace it as some variable names change.  The same set of source code works perfectly under Mac, but it just has this problem under win7.  Any idea about this?

Thanks