# Android build fails over com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android project were team primarily still uses Eclipse were added some 3rd parties libs, then Android Studio fails to run on device anf when running gradle build there is error:

```
:preDexDebug                      
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.umeng.socialize.bean.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.umeng.socialize.bean.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

And so on `warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute` 10 to 20 times for different files

(UPDATE these warnings seem to be older issue, see [Dx warning issues with latest Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976896/dx-warning-issues-with-latest-android-sdk) dated Nov 2 '11;
also in [Many issues after upgrading to Android Studio 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436463/many-issues-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-1-0))

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.tencent.mm.sdk.b.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

:dexDebug                    
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:dexDebug FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with no
n-zero exit value 2

* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Tried with

```
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
compileSdkVersion 19
```

and

```
buildToolsVersion "22"
compileSdkVersion 22
```

and

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
compileSdkVersion 21
```

for both

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
```

and
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'

**Eclipse ADT has no problem. How to overcome with gradle / Android Studio?**

Comment: Do you use, in your project, any library of any kind that already includes android support v4 and it's exporting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Guillermo Merino for hint.
Yes there is `android-support-v4.jar` there.

Solved with `exclude` as

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'android-support-*.jar')
    //...
}
```

see also

- [Gradle Exclude or add reference for JAR file hard included inside library classes.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965690/gradle-exclude-or-add-reference-for-jar-file-hard-included-inside-library-classe)
- [Top-Level Exception app:dexDebug --dex -no-optimize --output android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855722/top-level-exception-appdexdebug-dex-no-optimize-output-android-studio)
- [Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility)

Comment: If you answered your own question, please mark it correct.